# Node.js Response From Image Upload Without Refreshing Client Page

Tags: express

Problem Set: Client .posts image from form action='/pages/contact/image/something' to node.js and I .putItem to AWS S3. On the success response I would like to send the image url back to the client without refreshing the screen and update the location they wanted to add the image with the new src url.

If the page refreshes I lose the location where they wanted to upload the image. Open to any suggestions, I have looked at res.send, res.end, res.json, res.jsonp, res.send(callback): all of which overwrite(refresh) the client webpage with the array, text or context in general I am passing back to the client . Code below:

```
    myrouter.route('/Pages/:Page/Image/:Purpose')
        .post(function (req, res) {
            controller.addImageToS3(req, res)
                .then(function(imgurl){
                    //res.json({imgurl : imgurl});
                    //res.send(imgurl);
                    //res.end(imgurl);
                   //res.send(req.query.callback(imgUploadResponse(imgurl)))
                    <response mechanism here>
                    console.log('Image Upload Complete');
               }, function (err){
                    res.render('Admin/EditPages', {
                       apiData : apiData,
                       PageId : PageId
                    });
               });
        });
```

Ideally there could be a passed parameter to a javascript function that I could then use: Example:

```
function imgUploadResponse(imgurl){
    // Do something with the url
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You, as a developer, have full control over the s3 url format. It follows a straightforward convention:

> s3-region.amazonaws.com/your-bucket-name/your-object-name.

For example:

> https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/some-random-bucket-name/image.jpg

While I would recommend keeping those details in the back-end, if you really want to avoid using res.send, you can basically make the front-end aware of the url formatting convention and present the url to the user, even before the image was actually uploaded (just need to append the name of the image to the s3-region.amazonaws.com/your-bucket-name)

Also, I'm not sure why your page would refresh. There are ways to refresh content of your page without refreshing the whole page, the most basic being [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp). Frameworks like angular provide you with [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) that allow you to do back-end calls from the front-end.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Due to our setup the image name appends a random number in order to alleviate image overwriting. It would be very common for one of our clients to upload /house.jpg several times and consistently overwrite other photos stored in S3 that they use on other pages.

Comment: I have looked at using AJAX and on the success handler getting the url but have had issues posting the blob to node.js and routing that request to s3 for upload. I would prefer to use form tag and onchange upload the photo from the file input tag. The form tag neatly puts the file, name and other attributes in the files.file object and is easily accessible on node.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. If you were using a framework, you'd have plenty of libraries for file upload but I guess you might be working on an older system.
At this point the only workaround I see would be to generate the random hash on the client side and prepend that before sending the file to the back-end in which case you can know what your url will be. Not optimal but could do the job and preserve the unicity of image names.